# Linq: Group on list inside lists

Tags: linq, group-by, filtering

Let's say I have a list of lists.
For each item in this list , I have a list of custom objects.

These objects are as such:

```
public string Field1
public string Field2
public string Field3
```

What I'd like to achieve through Linq: filter out of my list of lists all the objects which have the same three fields, which are not the first element of their list and keep only the first one.

So let's say I have two lists listA and list B in my list.

listA has three objects object1, object2 and object3.

```
object1.Field1 = "a"    object1.Field2 = "A"    object1.Field3 = "1"  
object2.Field1 = "a"    object2.Field2 = "B"    object2.Field3 = "2"  
object3.Field1 = "a"    object3.Field2 = "C"    object3.Field3 = "3"
```

listB has three objects object4, object5 and object6.

```
object4.Field1 = "a"    object4.Field2 = "A"    object4.Field3 = "1"  
object5.Field1 = "a"    object5.Field2 = "B"    object5.Field3 = "2"  
object6.Field1 = "a"    object6.Field2 = "D"    object6.Field3 = "3"
```

In this example, object1 and object4 are the same, but because they are first in their respective list, they are not filtered out.
However, object2 and object5 having the same three fields values, only one of them will be kept so that at then end of my process, I'll have my two list like so:

listA has three objects object1, object2 and object3.

```
object1.Field1 = "a"    object1.Field2 = "A"    object1.Field3 = "1"  
object2.Field1 = "a"    object2.Field2 = "B"    object2.Field3 = "2"  
object3.Field1 = "a"    object3.Field2 = "C"    object3.Field3 = "3"
```

listB has now two objects object4 and object6.

```
object4.Field1 = "a"    object4.Field2 = "A"    object4.Field3 = "1"  
object6.Field1 = "a"    object6.Field2 = "D"    object6.Field3 = "3"
```

I've been scratching my head for hours about this to no avail. I cannot do a foreach list of lists look into all the other lists  as it would cause a performance problem (I can potentially have 1000000 lists of lists).

Anyone with an idea for this?

Comment: I think you will have very very big performance issue with 1000000 lists of lists. Is there any option to get filtered data from database?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Unfortunately this is not an option for me. You're right it would have been much simpler but I cant do that. I think what I can do is add an id field, then I could get the ids of the objects which are the same then filter them out of my list of lists. The question is how can I group by Field1, Field2 and Field3 through  all the different lists in my list.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky it's not efficient either. I'm going to put the list of lists in an xml file and work with it to delete the nodes I want to filter...

Comment: So your input is n lists and you want exactly one copy of each object across all lists (discounting the first element)? About the first element requirement, what if `object4` was instead the second item of the second list. Would you want that filtered out as well? I have an idea of a solution, but I'm not sure it if will be as performant as you hope with 1000000 lists.

Answer (score 1):

Why does it have to be LINQ? A simple iterator block solves the problem quite nicely.

The code below assumes you have overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your object to check for equality on the 3 fields. If that is not possible, use a custom equality comparer instead (to be passed in the HashSet constructor)

```
static IEnumerable<List<T>> GetFilteredList<T>(IEnumerable<List<T>> input)
{
    var found = new HashSet<T>();

    foreach (var list in input)
    {
        var returnList = new List<T>(list.Capacity);
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            // the first item is always added
            // any other items are only added if they were 
            // never encountered before
            if (list.Count == 0 || !found.Contains(item))
            {
                found.Add(item);
                returnList.Add(item);
            }
        }
        yield return returnList;
    }
}
```

If you can stick with `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` as the return value, another approach that only sweeps the input just once could be something like this (without creating intermediary lists):

```
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetFilteredList<T>(IEnumerable<List<T>> input)
{
    var encounteredElements = new HashSet<T>();

    foreach (var list in input)
    {
        yield return Process(list, encounteredElements);
    }
}

static IEnumerable<T> Process<T>(IEnumerable<T> input, 
                                 HashSet<T> encounteredElements)
{
    bool first = true;
    foreach (var item in input)
    {
        if (first) yield return item;
        if (!encounteredElements.Contains(item))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        encounteredElements.Add(item);
        first = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't there be performance issues if I have a huge quantity of lists in the input List?

Comment: well, what is the performance of looping through all items? You won't be able to do better than that, in which case you probably want to look at other solutions than in-memory processing.